# CWiseNullaryOp, Identity, sparse csr

Tags: c++, matrix, sparse-matrix, eigen

How can I express the identity matrix with CWiseNullaryOp?

I don't want a dense matrix. I want a csr sparse matrix.

we know row arrays and column arrays beforehand as it has values only on the diagonal.

The value that needs to be stored is 1, the only nnz of the marix.

I can compute the algorithm for these 3 arrays, but then I'm stuck on how to implement it. Do I need instead to write 3 functors that behave as arrays and use them with map function to map them into a sparse matrix?

Do I need instead to write the whole sparse matrix as a functor? And in that case, how? I've seen the documentation but my understanding of C++ is really basic and I need some hours to understand all that. An example on what i actually need could be both appreciated and useful to better understand how to write these things.

Comment: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SparseMatrix.html#aa4064cc1e3a4038cf09ff03af5a3ffb5

Comment: @chtz is it going to store some elements though? Identity is completely computable with an algorithm instead of storing elements. Pus I'm using sparse matrices, so sparse kronecker products. It is even easier to write an algorithm to compute the identity matrix in csr format. Youd don't need to store anything. It's hiper easy to use it in various operations. Don't know if that helps me in this direction

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the Identity matrix? If you want to use it inside expressions, just use the `Matrix<>::Identity()`.

Comment: that's a dense matrix algorithm. If I use kronecker sparse product it's better to use a sparse algorithm instead. Faster and it recognizes it's sparse as well. So whichever dense matrix i use, the output is psarse